# How can i insert element an element into BST?

Tags: c++, binary-search-tree

I've to build a binary search tree using two classes (1-BSTnode,2-BSTFCI), and i faced a problem with (insert) function.
when i did a test for this function , it gives me run time error

can anyone help me please?

This is the definition of the BSTnode:

```
template <class T>
class BSTnode
{
public:
    T data;
    BSTnode<T>* left;
    BSTnode<T>* right;
    BSTnode()
    {
        left = right = NULL;
    }
};
```

This is the definition of the BSTFCI:

```
template <class T>
class BSTFCI
{
public:
    BSTnode<T>* root;
};
```

and this is the insert function.

```
template <class T>
BSTnode<T>* BSTFCI<T>::Insert(BSTnode<T>*& node,T value)
    {
/// If the tree still empty.
    if(node == NULL)
    {
        node = create_new_node(value);
    }
    if(value < node->data)
    {
        node->left = Insert(node->left, value);
    }else if(value > node->data)
    {
        node->right = Insert(node->right,value);
    }

    return node;
}
```

main function

```
int main()
{
    BSTFCI<int> o;
    o.Insert(o.root,6);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. In particular: what is `create_new_node` ?

Comment: maybe discuss the logic of your `insert` with your rubber duck. I dont see how the recursion could ever stop. Maybe the second `if` should be `else if` ?

Answer (score 0):

I implemented and checked your code. The only problem I found is that you have not initialized the value of root as NULL in BSTFCI constructor. You need to write the constructor of BSTFCI and assign the initial value of **root** as **NULL**.

```
class BSTFCI
{
public:
    BSTnode<T>* root;
    BSTnode<T>* Insert(BSTnode<T>*& node,T value);
    BSTFCI()
    {
        root = NULL;
    }
};
```